# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty - Hashicorp Vault

Tags: spring, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I'm following `Vault Configuration` example referring from: https://spring.io/guides/gs/vault-config/. When I am executing the code I am getting below error.

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultPropertySourceLocator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapPropertySourceConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultPropertySourceLocator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultSessionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultSessionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientAuthentication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication]: Factory method 'clientAuthentication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:191) [spring-cloud-context-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:105) [spring-cloud-context-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:71) [spring-cloud-context-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) [spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) [spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) [spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127) [spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.GsVaultConfigApplication.main(GsVaultConfigApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.ClientAuthenticationFactory.createClientAuthentication(ClientAuthenticationFactory.java:108) ~[spring-cloud-vault-config-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration.clientAuthentication(VaultBootstrapConfiguration.java:206) ~[spring-cloud-vault-config-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6715ca8.CGLIB$clientAuthentication$2(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-vault-config-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6715ca8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$78ac2bde.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-vault-config-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6715ca8.clientAuthentication(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-vault-config-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

MyConfiguration.java

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("example")
public class MyConfiguration {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

GsVaultConfigApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfiguration.class)
public class GsVaultConfigApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GsVaultConfigApplication.class, args);
    }

    private final MyConfiguration configuration;

    public GsVaultConfigApplication(MyConfiguration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GsVaultConfigApplication.class);
        LOGGER.info("----------------------------------------");
        LOGGER.info("Configuration properties");
        LOGGER.info("        example.username is {}", configuration.getUsername());
        LOGGER.info("        example.password is {}", configuration.getPassword());
        LOGGER.info("----------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=gs-vault-config
spring.cloud.vault.token=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled=true
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-vault-config</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>gs-vault-config</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spring Cloud Configuration integrations use the [bootstrap context](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html) for their configuration. Bootstrap context is configured before spinning up the application context so configuration integrations can load and initialize `PropertySource`s that are then used in the application context.

As a consequence, rename your `application.properties` to `bootstrap.properties`.