# Not able to disable Spring Vault during unit tests in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-vault-config

I've disabled the spring vault in my unit tests. But however, its still enabling it and running in the back ground. This is my code. Is there any issue in the below code

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.cloud.vault.enabled=false", classes = 
 DummyTest.class)
public class DummyTest{
    
    @Test
    public void getDummyTest() throws Exception{
        assertTrue(true);
    }
    
}
```

Following is the exception that its printing in the console

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty
at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:287)
at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.ClientAuthenticationFactory.createClientAuthentication(ClientAuthenticationFactory.java:108)
at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration.clientAuthentication(VaultBootstrapConfiguration.java:206)
at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d0bfc2.CGLIB$clientAuthentication$3(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d0bfc2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7f75c921.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d0bfc2.clientAuthentication(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
... 99 more
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem yesterday. The issue had been solved in this question: [Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token (spring.cloud.vault.token) must not be empty - Hashicorp Vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53933508/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-token-spring-cloud-vault-token)

Your test class is loaded in application context, but the error you get is thrown in bootstrap context. `spring.cloud`-properties are always loaded in that context. The solution is to set `spring.cloud.vault.enabled=false` in bootstrap context, e.g. you can put it in a bootstrap.yml file in your test-ressources.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Cloud Vault doesn't support bootstrap.yml anymore. Hence, you have to write the configuration in application.yml.

When you use application context: WebFluxTest, SpringBootTest, Autowire, etc. the test loads application context that results in reading the application.yml file

To avoid loading Vault in UTs you need to create an application.yml file in the resources folder in the Test folder and add the following line:

```
spring.cloud.vault.enabled: false
```

Note: yml = properties (whatever format you use)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to fix this issue using

```
azure.keyvault.enabled=false
```